# $A$ speak truth $3$ out of $4$ times and $B$ speak truth $2$ out of $3$ times

Tags: probability

$A$ speak truth $3$ out of $4$ times and $B$ speak truth $2$ out of $3$ times. A dice is thrown . Both assert that the number turned up is $2$. Find the probability of their assertion.

My question is when they lie, i.e. when number appeared on dice is not $2$, then do we have to also consider the probability of them choosing to speak $2$. e.g. Suppose $1$ appears on dice, then while lying they may speak any of five remaining numbers

Comment: We need a model for lying.  (Bet I don't say that again this month.)  Suppose the die comes up $1$.  If someone lies, do they pick one of the other $5$ results with probability $1/5$ each?

Comment: Actually, the term "Find the probability of their assertion" is not  clear.

Comment: @trueblueanil I think it simply means, "What is the probability that they both say that number on dice is 2? "

Comment: In that case, assuming that they are equally likely to assert any wrong number when lying, $1/5$ will come in.

Comment: It is reasonable to assume that if $A$ decides to lie, she chooses each of the alternatives to the truth with equal probability. But that should have been made explicit.

Comment: Reading through the problem statement, after the sentence "Both assert that the number is $2$" I expected to be asked to find the probability that the number on the die actually was $2$. The thing we're actually asked for, "the probability of their assertion," is vague enough that it _might_ mean "the prior probability they both would have said $2$", or it might mean "the probability that the number actually _is_ $2$ (that is, both their assertions are true), given all these events".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have commented, the term "Find the probability of their assertion" is not clear to me.

Going by your interpretation that it simply means P(both assert "two"),
assuming that their assertions are independent,
and that they are equally likely to choose each wrong number when lying,

P($2$ and both assert "two) $= \frac16 \frac34 \frac23 = \frac1{12}$

P(not $2$ and both assert "two") $ = \frac56 (\frac15 \frac14)(\frac15 \frac13)= \frac1{360}$

Add the two.

Comment: Why the two $\frac15$s in P(not 2 and both assert "two")?

Comment: @GoodDeeds: If it is not $2$, **both** have to assert "two" while lying.

Comment: But doesn't $\frac14.\frac13$ cover that? The assumption is that they are independent.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Say, A lies asserting "three", B lies asserting "four". This won't do, both need to asert "two" while lying.

Comment: I get it now, thank you.