# probability question and any theorem related to it.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A man speaks true $3/4$ times. A die is thrown and he reports it to be $4$ . what is the probability that it is actually four.

**MY TRY**

So probability of him speaking truth is $3/4$ so favourable cases are $3/4 \times 1/6=1/8$ now total cases are where he speaks true, false so its $3/4 \times 1/6+1/4 \times 5/6=1/3$ so probability is $3/8$ . Is my reasoning right? And is there any theorem for these sums.

Comment: The probability that the die came up $4$ is $3/4$. The fact that a die does not always come up $4$ is irrelevant. (Why is that so?)

Comment: No its probability of man speaking truth i have included the question tell me whats wrong in my reasoning

Comment: I see that now...easily missed subtlety there: he might say $4$ when it isn't actually a $4$. This problem is actually ill-defined is a subtle way: Will the man always report what the roll is? (honestly or not)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's just the phrasing, but I would not agree with your calculation.

The problem does not explain the nature of a lie. I would have thought the natural interpretation here was that when he lies he chooses a false answer uniformly among the options.  Assuming this to be the correct reading your second term ought to read $$\frac 14\times\frac 56\times \frac 15=\frac 1{24}$$

Further, your "denominator" needs to be the total probability that he says "I threw a $4$".  Thus I would see the correct answer as $$\frac {\frac 16\times \frac 34}{\frac16\times \frac 34+\frac 1{24}}=\frac {\frac 18}{\frac 4{24}}=\frac 34$$

Comment: No but answer is $3/8$ and i have typed whats in my book seems incorrect to me as the language is not very clear so i put it on MSE

Comment: If, for whatever reason, we imagine that his lie is ALWAYS "I threw a $4$" in the cases when he did not throw a $4$ then the computation gives the probability that he reports a $4$.  That seems very flawed to me...first of all, that's a weird way to interpret "lie" and second the question is asking for the probability that the throw was actually $4$, not the probability that he said it was.

Comment: But answer still is $3/8$ how to go for it?

Comment: The reason for the $\frac{1}{5}$ term is that in the case that he is lying, not only is there a $\frac{5}{6}$ of not rolling a $4$, but there is also only a $\frac{1}{5}$ chance that he would lie by saying $4$ (this assumes he chooses uniformly over possible dice rolls that aren't what was actually rolled when lying).

Comment: @ArchisWelankar  I do not believe the answer is $\frac 38$.  I think it more likely that the book is in error.  I'm sure there are some related questions for which the answer is $\frac 38$ (I suggested one) but...

Comment: @ArchisWelankar  Just to stress:  It is absolutely necessary to clarify the nature of "lie".  In my calculation I assumed that the choice "lie/truth" was independent of the throw and that the lie was a uniform choice among the (false) options.  To be clear, I made that up.  It seems reasonable to me but the problem doesn't say it.  Maybe the man loves the number $4$...maybe he always says the truth if he gets a $4$ and when he doesn't he is inclined to lie and say he did.   That would give a very different answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is **given** that the man says $4$

Assuming that when he lies, he chooses the number randomly,

P(actually $4$ | man says $4$) = $\dfrac {(1/6 \times 3/4)}{(1/6\times 3/4) + (5/6\times 1/5\times 1/4)}= 3/4$

**Added break-up of denominator and reference to another question**

P($4$ and says $4$) = $1/6\times 3/4$
P(not $4$ and says $4$) = $5/6\times 1/5\times 1/4$

See a more complicated version of a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685158/a-speak-truth-3-out-of-4-times-and-b-speak-truth-2-out-of-3-times/1685205#1685205)

Comment: So please can you tell me why my textbook has done it as $5/6*1/4$

Comment: The book seems to assume that if it is not $4$ and he lies, he will say $4$, but he could say any of the numbers other than the correct one.